# Set the height according to the image with dynamic height

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

At the moment, I am using the following code:

**CSS**

```
.photo-medium {
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-color : #222222;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : center center;
    background-size : contain;
    border-radius : 0;
    margin : 0 0 30px -10px;
    width : 100%;
}
```

**PHP & HTML**

```
# VARIABLE
$photo_750 = 'images/photos/'.$photo['data_file_name'].'-750.'.$photo['data_file_type'];

# DIMENSION
list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($photo_750);


# THE PHOTO
echo '<div class="photo-medium" style="background-image: url('.url($photo_750).'); height: '.$image_height.'px;"></div>';

# THE CONTENT
echo '<div style="margin-top: '.$image_height.'px;">';
    echo '...';
echo '</div>';
```

And here's how it looks like with that code (resize your browser window to under 750 pixels to see it): http://mitt-galleri.nu/P1290364.

With this solution, the height of the `DIV` are always as height as the image, no matter what the size of the window are. I want to set the height of the `DIV` (not only the image) according to the image's height. I have tested `min-height: 100%` but the background color are still visible. The `DIV` just getting smaller on the height than without `min-height: 100%`.

I also have `margin-top: '.$image_height.'px` on the content below `photo-medium` since I'm using `position: absolute`. I also want this to have a dynamic height, according to the image's height.

How can I fix this "problem"?

Comment: Have you tried setting the height to `auto`?

Comment: No, but now I have. The image disappeared completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really have to, why put it as background image? Add it as an img tag, set width 100%, height auto, and don't set any height on the parent div.

Comment: That's a solution, yes, but I prefer to use `background-image` more. But if I can't fix this "problem" with the help of your brilliant minds, I can use your solution

Comment: There's no way to auto-adjust the div according to it's background image size,  unless you want to add a bunch of javascript logics to it, and any backend solutions will work only on load, not on resize.

Comment: Ok. Then I'm going to use your solution. Many thanks :)